# Responsive module and tooltip module

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-oriented

Recently, I've noticed that my code looks so ugly because there were a bunch of functions and global variables.  So, I started reading a little bit about design patterns. Now I come with something that's working for me, but I am not sure if it's good practice.

Anyway, I would like you to take a look at the code and tell me what can I improve.  I'd also like to know a better way to start using modular pattern in JavaScript.  Finally, I'd like suggestions on material for learning about modular pattern and JavaScript.

```
var responsiveModule = {

    settings: {
        device: false,
        button: $(".responsive-btn"),
        target: $("nav ul"),
        mobileClass: "toggle-menu",
        bgImage: '<img class="background-image" src="img/background.jpg" alt="">',
        bgImageSelector: $(".background-image"),
        windowWidth: $(window).width(),

    },

    init: function(){
        responsiveModule.checkDevice();
        responsiveModule.replaceImages();
        responsiveModule.bindFunctions();
        responsiveModule.listenResize();
    },

    checkDevice: function(){
        if(this.settings.windowWidth > 992){
            this.settings.device = "desktop";

        } else {
            this.settings.device = "mobile";
        }
    },

    bindFunctions: function(){
        var buton = this.settings.button,
            muelleBtn = this.settings.muelleBtn;
        buton.on("click touchstart", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            responsiveModule.animateMenu(responsiveModule.settings);
        });
    },

    animateMenu: function(settings){
        var device = settings.device,
            target = settings.target,
            mobileAnimation = settings. mobileClass;

        if(device == "mobile"){
            target.toggleClass(mobileAnimation);
        }
    },

    replaceImages: function(){
        var bgContainer = $("#main-content"),
            bgImage = responsiveModule.settings.bgImage,
            device = responsiveModule.settings.device,
            backgroundSelector = $(".background-image");

        if(device == "desktop" && backgroundSelector.length == 0){
            bgContainer.append(bgImage);
        }else if(device == "mobile" && backgroundSelector.length == 1){
            backgroundSelector.remove();
        }
    },

    listenResize: function(){
        $(window).on("resize", function(){
            responsiveModule.checkDevice();
            responsiveModule.replaceImages();
            responsiveModule.settings.windowWidth = $(window).width();
        });
    }


}

var tooltipModule = {

    settings: {
        tooltipState: false
    },

    init: function(){
        tooltipModule.bindUIfunctions();
    },

    bindUIfunctions: function(){
        var device = responsiveModule.settings.device;
        if(device == "mobile"){
            $(".ship").on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                tooltipModule.manageTooltip(e);
            });
        }else{
            $(".muelle-item").addClass("desktop");
        }
    },

    manageTooltip: function(e){
        var tooltip = $(e.currentTarget).next(),
            tooltips = $(".tooltip");

        tooltips.removeClass("display");
        tooltip.addClass("display");
    }


}


$(document).on("ready", function(){
    responsiveModule.init();
    tooltipModule.init();   
});
```

Comment: Contrary to some of the answers below, note that a lot of people define prototypes as a *form of OOP* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186244/what-does-it-mean-that-javascript-is-a-prototype-based-language

Answer (score 1):

The best pattern to start "OOP" in JavaScript is the Revealing Pattern:

```
var revealed = function(){
   var a = [1,2,3];
   var abc = function(){
     return (a[0]*a[1])+a[2];
   }

   return {
      name: 'revealed',
      abcfn: abc
   }
}();
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647258/how-to-use-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript).

Then read [this book](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

And learn RequireJS, which will increase the modularity of your code and will load your JS files on demand.

I see you are using JS for create HTML elements.  To help you with this, take a look at UnderscoreJS templates and Mustache.

Comment: That “revealing pattern” is not related to OOP.

Comment: why not, don't is encapsulation the key concept of OOP?

Comment: @icktoofay could you explain more why is thtath  revealing pattern not related to OOP?

Comment: @Claudio: Object-oriented programming centers around objects, usually with functionality attached. I'll admit that that “revealing pattern” *does* create an object, but it's only one, ever, and that one object only functions as a set of namespaced variables, and I don't think that utilizing an object for that purpose counts as object-oriented programming.

Comment: @icktoofay as you see, I use quotes to refer to the js's OOP, because we have limitations in javascript, but in my opinion this is the best pattern to simulate an "OOP" in js.

Comment: @Claudio: I very much disagree; if you had a function to create objects, perhaps with functionality attached, and you could reasonably have multiple of them, then I think you'd have something that could be called object-oriented programming. Faking namespaces using anonymous functions is a neat trick, but it's not object-oriented programming.

Comment: @icktoofay Please don't stuck on names and features that other language implement, the main benefit of an OOP Language is to ensure that the outside don't change that.

Comment: @icktoofay [here](https://github.com/cld-santos/simplologia/blob/master/javascript-lessons/src/test/javascript/Basic-Objects.js) you can see an example of inheritance.

Comment: Requirejs doesn't increase modularity, per se... you don't even _have_ to learn to use it, just learn to require scripts on-the-fly... it's not that hard

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, I agreed with you, from the begin if you break your code in different files will be a good start.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question; it doesn't suggest any improvements to the sample of code.  This is CodeReview, not StackOverflow or Programmers.  (This failing also extends to Aegis and Pinoniq's answers, for that matter).

Comment: @Claudio: I'm as much as possible trying not to drag in any other languages, and I'm not contesting that JavaScript *can* be object-oriented (although that's a debate on its own); what I am contesting is that the revealing pattern you've shown is in itself object-oriented programming. Yes, that revealing pattern facilitates encapsulation of state, but you've only got one set of state within a namespace. Just because it encapsulates some state doesn't mean it's object-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea. JavaScript is prototype-based, not object-oriented. Embrace it!

- I would **strongly** advice you [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321812182) as well as [his blog](http://calculist.org/).
- Mess around with a REPL (nodejs / chrome dev tools), try to understand the unexpected or surprising behaviours.
- I found it useful sometimes to take a look at how your code is actually parsed, you can do this very easily online with the [Esprima project](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html).
- Make sure you completely understand how the prototype chain, functions and type coercion work, they are, imo, the core concepts in javascript.
- Get familiar with things such as IIFE (immediately invoked function expressions), scoping rules, etc.

Comment: -1 for stating that OO requires classes. Many OO languages use classes, but it is not essential.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_oriented http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html

Comment: The wikipedia page you link to isn't that correct imho. 'cloning existing objects to serve as prototypes' weut? ugh

Comment: @Pinoniq: That's how prototypes work. What's the problem?

Comment: @icktoofay: It's not really accurate for JS.  Prototypes in JS have very little to do with cloning; inheritance works mostly by setting the child's internal [[Prototype]] property to refer to the parent.  It's a pretty big difference, in that adding or changing the parent's behavior also changes the child (which wouldn't happen, or would happen in very odd and broken'ish ways, if the parent were cloned).

Answer (score -7):

Don't, just don't.

JavaScript is not an OO language, it is a prototype language, something a lot of people tend to forget.

[There are no 'classes' or 'interfaces' in javascript. Everything is an object. Even a function is an object](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

So how do JavaScript Objects work? what is 'this'? and what does 'new' do?
A good place to start is [understanding Scope and context](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/).

So, what are JavaScript objects?  Again there is a [good article](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-objects).

Once you understand that and you still feel like writing OO Js. There are tons of frameworks out there that pretend to be OO, my personal favorite MooTools.  These frameworks give you an interface to write OO-like code. But then again, in big applications that code tends to get slow, leak memory, since we forget how prototypes really work and what the 'new' operator means.

---

Let's recap and go back to your question. Your real problem is that your code is becoming hard to read.

So you are looking for a certain pattern in JavaScript to help in maintaining your code. My favorite pattern is the Module Pattern, but there are [many more very strong patterns for JavaScript](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

Comment: wow thank you for the awesome answer, I am going to read all the resources you post it in order to understand better the language!!!

Comment: @JhonnatanGonzalezRodriguez Pinoniq is quite wrong.  "Object Oriented" is a much debated term without one absolute definition, but it is broadly accepted that classes are one way to implement OO - and that prototypes are another.

Comment: -1 for saying that JavaScript isn't Object-Oriented and then stressing how *everything* in JavaScript is an **object**.  Can you spot the contradiction?  If I could -1 you again for recommending Adnan's book, I would;  It's a waffly rehash of things Adnan has read else where and doesn't understand.

Comment: @itbruce plus to your comment could you please recomend some resources different to Adna's to see your point? i will appreciate it

Comment: Object-oriented and everything is an object is not contradictory... Object-oriented design pattersn need abstract classes, interfaces,... these don't exist in javascript. Simply because everything is an object.
In javascript there is no inheritance chain, but prototypes.

Comment: Read the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107464/is-javascript-object-oriented His last sentence acutally sums up my answer. You can implement every OOD pattern, but everytime with special methods. (Just look at all the frameworks out there, the OO patterns don't simply work out of the box)

Comment: I really don't think you've understood the debate on that page.

Comment: @JhonnatanGonzalezRodriguez My usual recommendation for people new to JavaScript is to start with Douglas Crockford's website and his book, JavaScript: The Good Parts.  http://javascript.crockford.com/  Looking at your code, I think you need to get a better feel for the basics of the language before reaching for larger patterns.  Patterns are overused, mostly by people who don't understand their language of choice well enough to know where they are truly appropriate.

Comment: @Pinoniq javascript not only has object oriented capability, it has strong object oriented capability. Yes, it is a prototype based programming and that is in turn a style of object oriented programming.